# Excel - Multiple column search and return value from matched cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

i would like some help with the below. This is the first table whereby it will consist of the employee name, day, start time, end time. (This is a table that expands when more inputs are entered in)

Note : The names and days can be repeated as below, whereby AAA is repeated twice, and Monday is repeated thrice.

```
Name  Day      Start    End
AAA Monday      08:00   23:00
BBB Tuesday     08:00   16:00
CCC Monday      08:00   12:00
AAA Saturday    10:00   17:00
DDD Wednesday   08:00   23:00
EEE Sunday      08:00   23:00
BBB Friday      08:00   15:00
FFF Monday      08:00   23:00
```

The second table will look like this, "Monday" and "CCC" is the input value and to find the time range in the table above and display "In range" or "Out of range" in the table below.

So in here, input of "Monday" and "CCC" will gives "In range" for the cells from 8.00 to 12.00, and "Out of range" for all the other unrelated ones.
(This is a fixed table, from 8.00am to 23.30pm)

All help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Monday  CCC
8:00    In range
8:30    In range
9:00    In range
9:30    In range
10:00   In range
10:30   In range
11:00   In range
11:30   In range
12:00   In range
12:30   Out of range
13:00   Out of range
13:30   Out of range
14:00   Out of range
14:30   Out of range
15:00   Out of range
15:30   Out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS to return the times based on the criteria and MEDIAN to test if in the middle:

```
=IF(MEDIAN(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,$G$1,A:A,$H$1),SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,$G$1,A:A,$H$1),G2)=G2,"In range","Out of range")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, i noticed there is an issue here whereby if the employee range is lets say at 22:30, the "out of range" will stop at 22:00, instead of 22:30.

Is there a way to determine the 30mins interval too?

Comment: That has to do with the fact that it is a floating point error.  If you type the time in C and D, you will need to type the times in G and not use autofill or drag fill.  The decimal places get off when it is dragged down, and the numbers are no longer in sync.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't see any difference on the formula bar so i've not expected this to happen. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excel stores time as a decimal of one day.  So as we drag the decimals down 12-15 significant digits gets off, not enough to make a change to the time shown, but enough to through of the equalities.